# C-style casting confusion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I'm reading someone's (public) source code and I've come across this line and have no idea what it does. I've tried decomposing it but it always ends up confusing me in spite of what I try.

```
uintptr_t* pInterfaceVTable = (uintptr_t*)*(uintptr_t*)pd3dDevice;
```

`pd3dDevice` is a `LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9`, which is a `IDirect3DDevice9*`. An `IDirect3DDevice9` is a class that inherits off `IUnknown`, and both implement a bunch of virtual functions.

Could someone more worldly please help me with what this code does, line-by-line?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: This is actually undefined behaviour. A correct way to write this would be like this: `uintptr_t * p; const char * q = reinterpert_cast<const char *>(pd3dDevice); std::copy(q, q + sizeof(uintptr_t *), reinterpret_cast<char *>(&p));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uintptr_t is an integer type that can store a pointer.

The author assumes (knows?) that the first entry in IDirect3DDevice9 is a pointer, so he casts  IDirect3DDevice9 to (uintptr_t*) and dereferences it to access that pointer. Then he casts that uintptr_t again to a pointer (to uintptr_t) to assign it to pInterfaceVTable.
As mentioned in the comment and by AndyT, that is were the used compiler stores the pointer to the VTable, but that is not guaranteed by C++.

Comment: How is the cast different from just `(uintptr_t*)pd3dDevice`?

Comment: @Kerrek: The pointer is dereferenced so you don't get the value of pd3dDevice, but the value to what pd3dDevice points to interpreted as an uintptr_t*

Comment: @Kerrek: Yes, that is the hint in my last sentence.

Comment: Well, there are two different sets of "not guaranteed" here. I'm referring to the act of dereferencing a pointer of the wrong type, which is UB. You're (I think) referring to the fact that the ABI and class layout interna are implementation-defined.

Comment: @Kerrek: not that I want to defend this sort of code, but how is casting a pointer to another pointer and then dereferencing that casted pointer UB other then that it is assuming a certain class layout?

Comment: That's just what the standard says. Dereferencing a pointer that isn't the address of an object of the same type is UB, with the exception of char pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the author dissects virtual table of IDirect3DDevice9 instance. I can imaging one reason for this - for code injection, or hooking. It's possible to insert custom code into IDirect3DDevice9 implementation to hook its methods invocation for number of reasons, e.g. to record games as a video

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have revised my question because its intent was unclear. What I really want to know is what each cast / pointer / dereference does in the (single) line of code that is now on the question.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. His answer wasn't up when I made that comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
uintptr_t* pInterfaceVTable = (uintptr_t*)*(uintptr_t*)pd3dDevice;
```

Looks like that does a cast to a uintptr_t* then dereferences the pointer, then casts the dereferenced result to a uintptr_t*